# Octave: mkoctfile not found when compiling a C++ file

Tags: c++, octave

I am trying to use Octave functions in C++. I install Octave-3.8.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.3 and follow the standalone program example on Octave [website](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs),

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>

int
main (void)
{
std::cout << "Hello Octave world!\n";

int n = 2;
Matrix a_matrix = Matrix (n, n);

for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (octave_idx_type j = 0; j < n; j++)
    a_matrix(i,j) = (i + 1) * 10 + (j + 1);

 std::cout << a_matrix;

return 0;
}
```

Then I type

```
      $ mkoctfile --link-stand-alone main.cpp -o standalone
```

But it shows mkoctfile: command not found. What is the problem?

I also tried to compile the C++ file with g++

```
     $ g++ -I /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0 main.cpp
```

but it shows 2 errors as follows. 
1) 'config.h' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead. 
2) fatal error: 'hdft.h' file not found.

Please help me!

Comment: How did you install Octave?

Comment: I used the binary installation. But now I can use it when I set the Environment viriable.

Comment: well, you will notice that binary appears as beta. As far as I understand, the recommended way to install Octave in Mac system is via a package manager such as homebrew or Fink.

Comment: @carandraug thanks for the kind comment. So in order to install octave via homebrew, should I uninstall the binary installation?

Comment: you probably don't really have to, but you probably should. Installing it via homebrew is likely to have its caveats but also be more documented. Note that as a Linux user, I'm biased in favour of package managers.

Comment: @carandraug I use Octave built with Homebrew and I have access to `mkoctfile`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that octave is not registered in your system properly, judging by the shell response.

Try invoking the command from inside the octave interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about on MacOS, but on Linux, `mkoctfile` is not bundled within the default Octave distribution.   Instead, it requires a supplementary package, `liboctave-dev`, that has to be installed in addition to Octave itself.

This is not documented in the Octave web tutorial.